# Ansible roles: change file extension

Tags: ansible

In a Vagrant setup, I use Ansible to provision the virtual machine.

In one of the Ansible roles, I have a task that copies some files inside `~/bin/` folder:

`~/bin/one.sh`
`~/bin/two.sh`

I want to create symlinks of those files so the end result looks like:

`~/bin/one.sh`
`~/bin/two.sh`
`~/bin/one`   (symlink to `~/bin/one.sh`)
`~/bin/two` (symlink to `~/bin/two.sh`)

How can I achieve that? So far I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
- name: Common tasks =>Create symlinks for utilities
  file: src=~/bin/{{ item }} dest=~/bin/  mode=755 state=link
  with_fileglob:
    - bin/*
```

I need to put a regex inside `dest=~/bin/` that takes the file name (like `one.sh`) and removes the extension (`one.sh` becomes `one`) but I'm not sure how to do it.

**Update**

I finally used this tasks:

```
- name: Copy common files to ~/bin
  copy: src={{ item }} dest=~/bin/  mode=755
  with_fileglob:
    - bin/*

- name: Ensure symlinks for utilities exist
  file: src=~/bin/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('(\w+(?:\.\w+)*$)', '\1') }} dest=~/bin/{{ item | basename | regex_replace('\.sh','') }} mode=755 state=link
  with_fileglob:
    - bin/*
```

Comment: @techraf I updated my question thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [other useful filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) chapter:

> To get the root and extension of a path or filename (new in version 2.0):
>
> ```
> # with path == 'nginx.conf' the return would be ('nginx', '.conf')
> {{ path | splitext }}
> ```

You need to reference the first element of the list, so:

```
- name: Common tasks => Ensure symlinks for utilities exist
  file: src=~/bin/{{ item }} dest=~/bin/{{ (item | splitext)[0] }} mode=755 state=link
  with_fileglob:
    - bin/*
```

---

Of course, the above task works given the provisions specified in the task which you later edited out of the question, because `fileglob` lookup is running locally on the control machine (and in the previous task you used to copy the same files, so this one assumes they exist on local machine).

If you want to run the task singlehandedly you'd have first to prepare a list of the files on the target node with the [`find` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) and then running the above looping over the results.

Comment: Is there a way to combine `with_fileglob` with `with_items` ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Combine in what way?

Comment: What I mean is that in one of my ansible roles I have some files inside `devenv\ansible\roles\common\files\bin` those are *.sh scripts that i want to create symlinks for inside the ~/bin/ folder of the VM.. so Instead of manually typing those file names, i want to get the names using `with_fileglob` and pass them into with_items.

Comment: I tried using `regex_replace` with this expression `\w+(?:\.\w+)*$` to extract file name but ansible says **invalid group reference**
`- name: Common tasks => Ensure symlinks for utilities exist
  file: src=~/bin/{{ item | regex_replace('\w+(?:\.\w+)*$', '\\g<1>') }} dest=~/bin/{{ (item | splitext)[0] }} mode=755 state=link
  with_fileglob:
    - bin/*` this is the regex: https://regex101.com/r/LOfN61/1

Answer (score 4):

I am using the following expression to change filename e.g. from `test.file.name.txt` to `test.file.name.csv`

```
"{{ ((item| splitext)[:-1] | join('.')) }}.csv"
```

This will split the item on any dot, cut the latest off and join all together again with a dot. After this you cann add the extension of your favour.